# Random entries from sqlite database in list view?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I've got a wierd bug. I have created a listview with headings using another listview using this http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/. Ive populated the headings list with a straight array (there aren't that many) and populated the items listview from a preexisting database. 
Both listviews show up fine and the items click through to the relevent selections ok, but there are entries on the list **from outside the search parameters**.

This is from the class that returns the lists:

```
private Cursor getBeginnersCursor()
{
    this.cursor = null;
    try{

        this.getmDB();
        if(this.mDB == null)
        {
            System.out.println("mDB = null");
        }

        this.cursor = mDB.query(TABLE_NAME,new String[]{KEY_ID,GAME_NAME}, "_id > 11 AND _id < 35",
                null,null,null,null);
        if(this.cursor != null)
        {
            this.cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        mDB.close();
        return this.cursor;
    }catch(SQLException e){
        throw e;
    }
}



private List<String> getBeginnersArrayList()
{
    this.getmDB();

    this.cursor = this.getBeginnersCursor();

    String result;

    for(this.cursor.moveToFirst(); !this.cursor.isAfterLast();this.cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        result = this.cursor.getString(1) + "\n";
        this.beginnersArrayList.add(result);
    }
    this.cursor.close();
    return beginnersArrayList;
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I worked it out. SQLite doesnt seem to treat text integer values the same as Integer values, so it was mixing the id 1 in between id's 9 and 10 and so on. Ive created another column to define the sections instead.